# how to get string from array edit text

Tags: android

i have edittexts those are made with for loop .how can i get  string typed in specific edit text ?

```
for (int r = 0; r < arraysize ; r++) {
EditText comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this);
                    comment_post[r].setLayoutParams(set_params2);
                    comment_post[r].setHint("Comment");
                    comment_post[r].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                     {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            toast(comment_post[r].getText().toString());
                        }
                    });
}
```

Attention : r variable returns last value because it grows in for loop so onClick return last value of comment_post[r] but i need choosed edit text value.
thanks for your attention

Comment: Question is not clear! can you explain little more ? 
Also what is  EditText comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this);
I am sure that will give compile error?

Comment: i have edit texts in array and i want get specific string typed in which one but because  counter grows in loop each edittext onClick returns last string of last edittext

Comment: @farshad you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot create EditText like this

```
EditText comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this);
```

Use below function to create it

```
for (int r = 0; r < arraysize; r++) {
        EditText comment_post = new EditText(this);
        //  comment_post.setLayoutParams(set_params2);
        comment_post.setHint("Comment");
        comment_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //  toast(comment_post.getText().toString());
            }
        });

  //todo here you should add edittext to the parent layout
   parent.add(comment_post);
    }
```

You can use the below method to get the edit text values

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
                EditText child = (EditText) parent.getChildAt(i);
                String value = child.getText().toString();
                list.add(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this doesnt work bc i didnt put full my code here but i found i must use array list.thanks for your attention and help

Comment: Yeah Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are not able to access EditTexts created but only the last one.
**First:**
Not sure what this code is, I am sure this will be throwing compilation error

```
EditText comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this);
```

Now here is my code to do what you need to do

```
          ArrayList< EditText > mEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();
          for (int r = 0; r < arraysize ; r++) {
                EditText comment_post = new EditText(context);
                comment_post.setHint("Comment");        
                comment_post[r].setLayoutParams(set_params2);
                comment_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        toast(comment_post.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
                //Add to any array if you need to access the EditText in future
                mEditTexts.add(comment_post);
            }
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

First you should initialize EditText like below

```
EditText[] comment_post =  new EditText[r.length];
```

then create object of that like this below -

```
comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this)
```

finally you can set id of every `EditText` like below and access the editText based on id - `comment_post[r].setId(r); // Set id like this`

```
for (int r = 0; r < arraysize ; r++) {
                    comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this)

                    comment_post[r].setLayoutParams(set_params2);
                    comment_post[r].setHint("Comment");
                    comment_post[r].setId(r); // Set id here
                    comment_post[r].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                     {
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                         toast(comment_post[v.getId()].getText().toString());// access by id
                        }
                    });
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: EditText comment_post[r] = new EditText(home.this);
please tell me how this line is working ?

Comment: @droidev Oh I have updated the post thanks for pointing out. :)